# flutter and dart project running properly in windows but not running on mobile

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\India\AndroidStudioProjects\employee_ui\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\India\AndroidStudioProjects\employee_ui\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\India.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\7f74a5mcaxfafgz2z9owrcxim).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried running it on windows and android but android is not running correctly.

Comment: Check your gradle distribution version in the gradle-wrapper.properties if possible download an updated one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.